# Sanitize query parameters in the URL with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Is there a way with mod_rewrite to sanitize an URL of this type:

```
https://www.example.com/blabla/?&param1=1&param2=2
```

to

```
https://www.example.com/blabla/?param1=1&param2=2
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^&(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?%1 [R=301,L]
```

That should basically do it. The RewriteCond matches on any query string that starts with `&`, and simply captures the rest.

And then you simply insert the back reference to that "rest" into the substitution URL, using `%1`.

---

Edit: Pattern changed to `(.*)` to capture *all* URL paths; back reference `$1` inserted into substitution URL.

Comment: Thanks @CBroe , I need this to work for all urls, not only for /blabla

Comment: I changed it to match all paths instead of a specific one.